# Need to highlighted only one tick from DataGrid based on condition(or at 0 position on Y Axis) in Line Chart D3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

[image]Please find my  [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/ka3ysvre/88/)

I want to highlighted dataGrid on YAxis at "0 position" in chart

**using tick:first-of-type line I can do at first line but I want at 0 position on  Y axis**

```
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
        .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type line")
  .attr("class", "axis_bar")
  .attr("stroke", "red"))
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line")
  .attr("class", "axis_y_tick")
  .attr("stroke", "#E8E8E8"))
```

```js
var data = [{
  "depotID": 115785,
  "depotName": "TestA",
  "materials": [{
      "materialTypeID": 1,
      "materialName": "materialA",
      "materialStocks": [{
          "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 315
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-11-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 315
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 315
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 309
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 91
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 78
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 64
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 52
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-06-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 39
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-07-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 25
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-08-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 14
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 11
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "materialTypeID": 2,
      "materialName": "materialB",
      "materialStocks": [{
          "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 3
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-11-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -8
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -19
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -30
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -38
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -51
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -59
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -72
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-06-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -81
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-07-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -91
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-08-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -98
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": -98
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "materialTypeID": 3,
      "materialName": "materialC",
      "materialStocks": [{
          "date": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 20
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-11-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 20
        },
        {
          "date": "2020-12-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 20
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-06-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-07-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-08-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        },
        {
          "date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00",
          "stock": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

let width = 900,
  height = 400,
  margin = 100;


var dates = [];
for (let obj of data[0].materials[0].materialStocks) {
  dates.push(obj.date);
}

var domain = d3.extent(dates);
var newStartDate = new Date(domain[0]).setDate(new Date(domain[0]).getDate() - 15);
var newEndtDate = new Date(domain[1]).setDate(new Date(domain[1]).getDate() + 15);

var xScaleTest = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date(newStartDate), new Date(newEndtDate)])
  .range([0, width - margin * 2]);


var yScaleTest = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([d3.min(data[0].materials, function(d) {
    return d3.min(d.materialStocks, function(d) {
      return d.stock;
    })
  }), d3.max(data[0].materials, function(d) {
    return d3.max(d.materialStocks, function(d) {
      return d.stock;
    })
  })])
  .range([height - margin, 0]).nice();

console.log(d3.min(data[0].materials, function(d) {
  return d3.min(d.materialStocks, function(d) {
    return d.stock;
  })
}));

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#xyAxes").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width + margin) + "px")
  .attr("height", (height + margin) + "px")
  .attr("style", "outline: thin solid black;")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScaleTest)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickSizeOuter(0)

  .tickSizeInner(-height + margin)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b -%Y"));

var minNumber = d3.min(data[0].materials, function(d) {
  return d3.min(d.materialStocks, function(d) {
    return d.stock;
  })
});

var maxNumber = d3.max(data[0].materials, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.materialStocks, function(d) {
    return d.stock;
  })
});

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScaleTest)
  .ticks(14)
  //    .tickValues(d3.range(minNumber, maxNumber, 20))
  .tickSize(-width + margin + 100);


var array1 = yAxis.scale().ticks();
console.log("Find tick " +
  array1

);


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis)
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type line")
    .attr("class", "axis_bar")
    .attr("stroke", "#BEBEBE"))
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line")
    .attr("class", "axis_y_tick")
    .attr("stroke", "#E8E8E8"));

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - (margin) / 2)
  .attr("x", 0 - ((height - margin) / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Value");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - 200) / 2) + " ," + (height - 50) + ")")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("date");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type line")
    .attr("class", "axis_bar")
    .attr("stroke", "red"))
  .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line")
    .attr("class", "axis_y_tick")
    .attr("stroke", "#E8E8E8"))

d3.selectAll("g.y.axis g.tick line")
  .filter(function(d) {
    console.log("check Filted d" + d);
    return d == 0;
  })
  .select('g.tick line') //grab the tick line
  .attr('class', 'quadrantBorder') //style with a custom class and CSS
  .style('stroke', 'red')


var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScaleTest(new Date(d.date))
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock)
  });

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

var groups = lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(this.data[0].materials).enter()
  .append('g');

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal((d3.schemeCategory10));

//line
groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.materialStocks)
  })
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5") //dashed array for line;

//dot on line
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(this.data[0].materials)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", (d, i) => colors(i))
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .selectAll("dot")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.materialStocks;
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScaleTest((new Date(d.date)));
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScaleTest(d.stock);
  });
```

```css
svg {
  font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

text.title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #353535;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="xyAxes"></div>
```

Comment: I able to do this

Comment: d3.selectAll("g.tick line")
  .filter(function(d){ console.log("check Filted d" + d);return d===0 ;} )
  //.select('g.tick line') //grab the tick line
   .attr('class', 'quadrantBorder') //style with a custom class and CSS
   .style('stroke', 'red')

Comment: Do you mean you solved it?

Comment: yes I solved it @Ruben Helsoot. Thank you

Comment: In that case, please share your solution!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/ka3ysvre/130

d3.selectAll("g.tick line") 
.filter(function(d) { console.log("check Filted d" + d);return d===0 ;} ) 
//.select('g.tick line') //grab the tick line .attr('class', 'quadrantBorder') //style with a custom class and CSS .style('stroke', 'red')

Comment: As an answer, I meant, so it can help future users (:

Comment: Is it good explanation @@Ruben Helsloot?

d3.selectAll("g.tick line") 
.filter(function(d) { console.log("check Filted d" + d);return d===0 ;} )
.attr('class', 'quadrantBorder') //style with a custom class and CSS .style('stroke', 'red'

Comment: Can you help me here @@Ruben Helsloot

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506530/fill-same-line-color-in-to-circle-on-multi-line-chart-when-mouse-over-and-remove

Comment: I also added working  JSFiddle here for this question answer . So it will definitely help